# Convert date from mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss to this format (Fri, 11 Jul 2014 11:04:26 +0000) using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting date time in string format as `7/22/2014 9:41:19 AM`, now i want to convert it into format like this `(Tue, 22 Jul 2014 09:41:19 +0000)`

how do i convert it using c#?

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't have `M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt` format as a standard date and time format (probably it doesn't), you can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.DateTime.ParseExact(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) methods like;

```
string s = "7/22/2014 9:41:19 AM";
DateTime date;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    Console.WriteLine(date);
}
```

Then you can use [`DateTime.ToString(format)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get string representation of your `DateTime`.

```
date.ToString("ddd',' dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz",
              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

returns

```
Tue, 22 Jul 2014 09:41:19 +03:00
```

But [`zzz` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#zzzSpecifier) are not recomended for `DateTime` formattings. If your string representations should have some [offset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) values, parsing [`DateTimeOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) would be better in such a case. Becuase a `DateTime` does not store any offset value.